# Text input with react native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to create a text input box with react native.

The template (which works), is something like:

```
const App: () => React$Node = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <Text>Hello world</Text>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I've attempted the following text input scheme:

```
const App: () => React$Node = () => {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: ''};
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Text>Hello world</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40}}
        placeholder="Type here to translate!"
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        value={this.state.text}
      />
      <Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 42}}>
        {this.state.text.split(' ').map((word) => word && '').join(' ')}
      </Text>
    </>
  );
};
```

I get the following error:

> Error: TransformError SyntaxError: [Path]\App.js: Unexpected token, expected ";"

Usually, the format (which also works), is something like this:

```
export default class PizzaTranslator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: ''};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{padding: 10}}>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="Type here to translate!"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
          value={this.state.text}
        />
        <Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 42}}>
          {this.state.text.split(' ').map((word) => word && '').join(' ')}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

But I figure, there should be a way to just add a text input to the template with arrow functions.
Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a text input in React native is really simple. This should help.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TextInput, View, Text } from 'react-native';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {

const [value, setValue] = useState()
  return (
    <>
      <Text>Hello world</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={{height: 40}}
        placeholder="Type here to translate!"
        onChangeText={(text) => setValue(text)}
        value={value}
      />
      <Text style={{padding: 10, fontSize: 42}}>
        {value
        .split(" ")
        .map(word => word && "")
        .join(" ")}
      </Text>
    </>
  );
};

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code segment, simply copy-paste? It works on my side. I guess your code formatting creates the **SyntaxError**.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { SafeAreaView, View, Text, TextInput } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
        <TextInput
          style={{ height: 40 }}
          placeholder="Type here to translate!"
          onChangeText={text => setText(text)}
          value={text}
        />
        <Text style={{ padding: 10, fontSize: 42 }}>
          {text
            .split(" ")
            .map(word => word && "")
            .join(" ")}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;
```